# How to test for an Async side effect with Scala and Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I have a simple scenario where I do some work on 3rd party services and if there was a failure in one of them, then I want to clean up what was done.

The client does not need to wait for the cleanup to complete to get a response so the cleanup is done as a side affect, async function.

While using Mockito I want to `verify` that the cleanup method was called, but I am getting a race condition and a non deterministic test.

Here is the code snippet:

```
val eventualImage = imageService.saveImage(uploadedImage, None, parent, imageActions)
ScalaFutures.whenReady(eventualImage.failed, timeout(6 seconds), interval(15 millis)) { ex =>
  val x = Mockito.verify(mockS3Repository, Mockito.times(1)).deleteFileFromS3(s3Location) // where this function is pure async and nothing is waiting for her to complete
  ex shouldBe a [exception.type]
}
```

Is there any way I can wait for it to complete with out changing my code?

Comment: wrap in `eventually { }`?

Comment: Eventually the solution was found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Lodewijk Bogaards suggested in his comment.
using the eventually block solved my problem.

here is an example:

First add the `with Eventually` to your class declaration

And then the code from the question will be completed like so:

> ```
>       val eventualImage = imageService.saveImage(uploadedImage, None, parent, imageActions)
>       ScalaFutures.whenReady(eventualImage.failed, timeout(6 seconds), interval(15 millis)) { ex =>
>         ex shouldBe a [exception.type]
>         eventually(timeout(6 seconds), interval(15 millis)){
>           Mockito.verify(mockS3Repository, Mockito.times(1)).deleteFileFromS3(s3Location)
>         }
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can do [timeout-based verification](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) by calling the [`timeout`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#timeout(long)) method.

```
Mockito.verify(mockS3Repository, Mockito.timeout(5000)).deleteFileFromS3(s3Location)
```

Though you shouldn't need `times(1)`, as it's the default behavior, you can chain the two together by calling `timeout(5000).times(1)` and so forth.